# I kill process but come back

Tags: centos, process

I have a big problem on centos 6.4 i kill this(8904) but he come back and use the processor. How can we solve? I don't use apache(httpd) on my server. apache don't installed on machine. it's a zombie(or virus whatever)

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome! It would be better if you pasted text instead of including a screenshot. (You can edit your answer to change this.) Also, please tell us what commands you used to kill httpd, this will greatly help giving relevant answers.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this `httpd` process is either:

- An actual HTTP daemon, properly installed on your system: in this case, it's probably running monitored in a way that it gets automatically restarted when it goes down. You should use the proper (OS-specific) command to stop it; assuming init scripts, it would be something like `/etc/init.d/httpd stop`.
- Malware, running as root: in this case, your best bet is to wipe the machine's contents and reinstall. You should assume that all code and data is potentially compromised and not trust it.

Comment: i have receive fail error because apache is not installed on machine.

Comment: Then, as you suggest, it's probably malware, and the reasonable course of action is to back up any data (remembering it may have been tinkered with) and reinstall.